# Rewiring key stroke

Tags: keyboard

Some keys in my keyboard came to a sticky end after a catastrophic coke spill.
I do not intend to replace the old keyboard, since the whole laptop will be replaced next year.

The keys in question are: arrow up, arrow down, shift and '/'.

Shift has a twin brother on the west coast, who's doing all the work now, and I could rewire '/'  as 'delete' (now I realize this was a totally useless key) with the `xmodmap -e 'keycode 119=/'` command. That is, pressing 'delete' outputs a '/' now.

To discover how to replace the keys I use `xev`. I intend to replace arrow-up and arrow-down for pgup and pgdn respectively. Unhappily arrow-up/down do not have output. I know that pgup and pgdn are keycodes 112 and keycodes 117. But what should I fill in in the `xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>=<action>'` pattern as`xmodmap -e 'keycode 112='` and `xmodmap -e 'keycode 117='`

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the keyboard of the laptop itself, a quick and simple solution till the replacement of your laptop could be a cheap USB keyboard.

Comment: While Stephen Kitt's  will work, if there is any way you can, I suggest fixing, replacing, or circumventing (USB keyboard) the keyboard. The $50 saved is not worth the effort of retraining your self to type incorrectly, then to have to re-train yourself to type properly again.

Answer (score 12):

See `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` for the available key names:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112=Up'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117=Down'
```

(the prefixes need to be removed).